# Conditional Formatting in Excel within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Problem**

Is it possible to CF a range which is already Conditionally Formatted?

**So far what i have done**

```
=AND(B$5<=$C$2,$A6<=$C$3)
range=$B$6:$O$19
```

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30964816/Book.xls

C2 is number of columns (Varies B/W 2 and 14)

C3 is number of rows    (Varies B/W 2 and 14)

**What needs to be done**

I want to the CF applied only to periphery Cells only and make it look like this:

[image: example image of formating]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes.  Just uncheck "Stop If True" in the Conditional Rules Manager.

I was able to accomplish the periphery cells outline with:

Rule 1: `=AND(OR($A6=1,$A6=$C$3),B$5<=$C$2)`

Rule 2:  `=AND(OR(B$5=1,B$5=$C$2),$A6<=$C$3)`

You could also make a single rule with an OR between:
`=OR(AND(OR(B$5=1,B$5=$C$2),$A6<=$C$3),AND(OR($A6=1,$A6=$C$3),B$5<=$C$2))`